# Excel disregards decimal separators when working with Python generated CSV file

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am currently trying to write a csv file in python. The format is as following:

```
1; 2.51; 12
123; 2.414; 142
```

EDIT: I already get the above format in my CSV, so the python code seems ok. It appears to be an excel issue which is olved by changing the settigs as @chucksmash mentioned.

However, when I try to open the generated csv file with excel, it doesn't recognize decimal separators. 2.414 is treated as 2414 in excel.

```
csvfile = open('C:/Users/SUUSER/JRITraffic/Data/data.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";")
writer.writerow(some_array_with_floats)
```

Comment: This sounds like an Excel configuration issue. In Europe, the usage of the `.` and `,` characters are reversed from what Americans expect (e.g. `2.414,0` instead of `2,414.0`. Try changing the locale: [Excel change decimal separator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e)

Comment: @chucksmash This solved the issue, thank you. I can accept if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that the csv file is generated correctly as you want?  Also, try to specify the delimeter character that your using for the csv file when you import/open your file.  In this case, it is a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

For python 3, I think your above code will also run into a TypeError, which may be part of the problem.

I just made a modification with your open method to be 'w' instead of 'wb' since the array has float and not binary data. This seemed to generate the result that you were looking for.

```
csvfile = open('C:/Users/SUUSER/JRITraffic/Data/data.csv', 'w')
```

Comment: Not that according to csv.writer documentation "If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference." In other words 'b' is the safe bet, all the writer examples at https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer use 'b' and that's always worked fine for me.

Comment: 'w' creates the excel file with blank rows between rows with data. Using 'wb' fixes this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

**An ugly solution**, if you really want to use `;` as the separator:

```
import csv
import os

with open('a.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvfile.write('sep=;'+ os.linesep) # new line
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow([1, 2.51, 12])
    writer.writerow([123, 2.414, 142])
```

This will produce:

```
sep=;
1;2.51;12
123;2.414;142
```

which is recognized fine by Excel.

**I personally would go with `,` as the separator** in which case you do not need the first line, so you can basically:

```
import csv

with open('a.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile) # default delimiter is `,`
    writer.writerow([1, 2.51, 12])
    writer.writerow([123, 2.414, 142])
```

And excel will recognize what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this is to specify dialect=csv.excel in the writer. For example:

```
a = [[1, 2.51, 12],[123, 2.414, 142]]
csvfile = open('data.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=";", dialect=csv.excel)
writer.writerows(a)
csvfile.close()
```

Unless Excel is already configured to use semicolon as its default delimiter, it will be necessary to import data.csv using Data/FromText and specify semicolon as the delimiter in the Text Import Wizard step 2 screen.

Very little documentation is provided for the Dialect class at [csv.Dialect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect). More information about it is at [Dialects](https://pymotw.com/2/csv/#dialects) in the PyMOTW's "csv – Comma-separated value files" article on the Python csv module. More information about csv.writer() is available at https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer.